# Spring boot, angular 7 Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse when download a pdf

Tags: json, angular, spring

Here is my backend :

```
public ResponseEntity getTestByURL(String filename) throws IOException {

    File myExport = new File(location + filename);

    HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
    header.add("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);

    String absolutePath = myExport.getAbsolutePath();
    InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(absolutePath));

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .headers(header)
            .contentLength(myExport.length())
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"))
            .body(resource);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/url/{url}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE, method = GET)
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getTestByURL(@PathVariable(value = "url") String url) throws IOException {
    return testService.getTestByURL(url);
}
```

And frontend :

```
getPDF(url: string): Observable<HttpResponse<Blob>> {
    return this.http.get<HttpResponse<Blob>>(`${this.urlPDF}` + '/' + url, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/pdf',
        responseType : 'blob',
        Accept : 'application/pdf',
        observe : 'response'
        })
    });
}
```

Give me an error, HttpErrorResponse status: 200. "Http faillure during parsing ..."
"Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse"

Comment: you are getting this error at frontend or at backend?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are calling service without responseType params apart from HttpHeaders. HttpClient by default take this value as json. You will have to specify it.

https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest

see constructor signature:-
 constructor(method: string, url: string, third?: T | { **headers**?: HttpHeaders **responseType**?: "arraybuffer" | "blob" | "text" | "json"............ })

working code:-

```
let  headers= new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/pdf',
    responseType : 'blob',
    Accept : 'application/pdf',
    observe : 'response'
    })
  return this.httpClient.get(this.resourcePrefix+ '/test', {
    headers:headers , responseType: 'blob' 
});
```

For download you can google it. or I usually use this to download

```
this.httpService.test().subscribe(res =>{
  console.log(res);
  const file = res;
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([res as BlobPart], { type: 'application/pdf' }));

    var link = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
    link.href = url;
    link.download = 'test.pdf';
    link.click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
return this.http.get(`${this.urlPDF}/${url}`, { responseType: 'blob' })
```

Comment: this was used to pass headers in old `Http` but he is using `HttpClient` so you cannot send headers this way

Comment: This is valid in HttpClient too. I am using it in my current project in Angular 7